# i want to fetch the data of that three month whose sale is max from other month of current year in mysql

Tags: mysql

i tried this query

```
select  id, year(created_at) as year,month(created_at) as month,sum(grandtotal) as monthtotalsale 
from bookings
WHERE YEAR(created_at)=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) group by month(created_at)
order by id, year(created_at),month(created_at)
```

but this query return the total sale of each month
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the three month with the highest sale monthly for this year

```
SELECT 
    id,
    YEAR(created_at) AS year,
    MONTH(created_at) AS month,
    SUM(grandtotal) AS monthtotalsale
FROM
    bookings
WHERE
    YEAR(created_at) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
ORDER BY monthtotalsale DESC
LIMIT 3
```